# Db2 on Cloud - "Open console" button does not appear

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I am connected to the London server and I previously was able to use the console. However, when I do connect now to IBM Cloud, the option does not appear anymore. Picture attached on what I currently see.

Has anyone encountered this problem and, if so, how did you solve it?

[image: screenshot where 'open console' button used to appear]

Comment: What about "Open"?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the Db2 on Cloud Lite plan. That plan requires a renewal every 30 days. After it expires, you get a notice to renew. Thereafter, you should get a notice that the service and data have been decommissioned. It has a line:

> The service instance will still appear in your IBM Cloud account until you manually delete it.

Once it is deleted, you can sign up for the lite plan again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it was this. If someone else check on this answer, the plan that he mentions is the Db2 (not the user account, just the service).

Comment: UI does not reflect what's going on--shows a database that's decommissioned without showing it's decommissioned or prompting a manual delete. The status page shows that there's been issues, but implies they have been resolved. Resources page could even reflect db is dead and/or a prompt to create a new database. @data_henri, you probably saved me hours by letting me know the solution was in an email. Heh. Much appreciated. Just the kind of answer that I like to upvote.